# How to Scroll Multiple List View in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

In my case I have three list views and I am getting data from a server and sending  this to an adapter and the list views. First list View is scrolling perfectly while the other two list views have data and scrolls inside the list view not the whole screen. I want when I display all data it seems only one list view is there.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cerno.ui.CaseClientSearchList"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_search_caseClientList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type to search"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/case_search_listView"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/client_search_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1">
    </ListView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lead_search_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_data_searchlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#8d8d8d"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your ui. what actually you want to do.

Comment: can u show your ui? Whether all the 3 list view are in vertically aligned ie one by one?

Comment: *I want when I display all data it seems only one list view is there*, then use **ONE listView only**

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one listview in your activity then needs to `invalidate` those listviews. 
I guess you are reading data using `Asynktask` so in postexecute method just invalidate those listViews.

```
list1.invalidateViews();
list2.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Yes I have three asynctask to populate three list view . Your solution not working for me.